# IP address exception when adding to a list in C#

Tags: c#, list, ip-address

I am trying to read a set of IPs from a text file and add it to a IPAddress type list. An exception is raised on the line "listIPAdrrs.Add(IPAddress.Parse(list[i]));"

The exception is

> An invalid IP address was specified.

```
      List<string> list = new List<string>();
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\ips.txt");

        String[] str = text.Split('\n');

        for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
        {
            list.Add(str[j]);
        }

        List<IPAddress> listIPAdrrs = new List<IPAddress>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
             //Console.WriteLine(list[i]);

            listIPAdrrs.Add(IPAddress.Parse(list[i]));
        }
```

Comment: The exception seems to be pretty straightforward - what bad data are you supplying `IPAddress.Parse`?

Comment: Well, I would hazard a guess that the string is not a valid IP address in the loop at the point the exception is thrown! Is there a TryParse method on IPAddress? Didn't even know that was an FCL.

Comment: Consider using `File.ReadAllLines` instead, that'll save you a split and a loop: `List<string> list = new List<string>(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\ips.txt"));`

Comment: There is really no way to determine the problem here without also posting the contents of `ips.txt`.

Comment: Others have told you largeley what is wrong. My best guess is that you have a empty line at the end of your file which is causing an empty string to get passed to your parse method. Try parse will fix this well enough though you may went to explicitly check for an empty string before parsing so you can deal with that case as a simple skip as opposed to a truly bad text line which you might want to deal with differently.

Comment: The file probably contains `\r\n`, so splitting by `\n` still leaves the `\r`... `File.ReadAllLines()` as suggested by @zneak should fix this.

Comment: @user2969347 I'm glad it helped. I made the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that line endings are not necessarily just a `\n` (on Windows, it's most likely `\r\n`), and an IP address followed by the `\r` character isn't considered a valid IP address by `IPAddress.Parse`.

Fortunately, the guys who made the CLR thought it all out and got some pretty robust code, so we're going to use `File.ReadAllLines` instead.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\ips.txt"));
List<IPAddress> listIPAdrrs = new List<IPAddress>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    //Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
    listIPAdrrs.Add(IPAddress.Parse(list[i]));
}
```

If that's your kind of thing, you can also use LINQ to make it even shorter (though you lose the ability to use `TryParse` doing it):

```
List<IPAddress> listIPAdrrs = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\ips.txt")
    .Select(line => IPAddress.Parse(line))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You were trying to add a value which was not an IP address.

I would suggest to use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Then if the function returns `false` you know there was an invalid value and you could show a message showing the invalid value.